# Email Id from Address Book

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm getting all the contacts from the addressbook into my application, i just need to get  email address from the selected contact, here's my code

shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson

```
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:

(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker

      shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {


    // Select phone number


    ABMultiValueRef emailProperty = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);


    NSString *email = (__bridge NSString *)(emailProperty);

    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 320, 370);


    return NO;

}
```

Please help me out of this guys, Thanks in advance

Am printing it in the log given below

email string is ABMultiValueRef 0x1eb2ddb0 with 0 value(s)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
CFStringRef value, label;
ABMutableMultiValueRef multi = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
CFIndex count = ABMultiValueGetCount(multi);
if (count == 1)
{
    value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, 0);
    emailid = (NSString*) value;
    NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
    CFRelease(value);
}
else
{
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        label = ABMultiValueCopyLabelAtIndex(multi, i);
        value = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multi, i);

        // check for Work e-mail label
        if (CFStringCompare(label, kABWorkLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }
        else if(CFStringCompare(label, kABHomeLabel, 0) == 0)
        {
            emailid = (NSString*) value;
            NSLog(@"self.emailID   %@",emailid);
        }

        CFRelease(label);
        CFRelease(value);
    }
}
CFRelease(multi);
```

Comment: Am getting email id as null, i just copied ur code.. plz help me bro

Comment: bro its showing now, but it is showing only one email id for all the contacts in the log... any idea

Comment: oh god thats my fault some contacts doesn't have email ids. thats the problem. how can i show the contacts that having email ids.

Comment: i'm not a sure but may be it is not possible but one option is that  get person's email from your phonebook and store it to DATABASE ten retrive it...if my answer help you then please accept it :) thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

You can add below code to acces email form contacts..

```
-(IBAction)Contact 
{
    ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *picker = [[ABPeoplePickerNavigationController alloc] init];
    picker.peoplePickerDelegate = self;
        [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];
    [picker release];}
- (void)peoplePickerNavigationControllerDidCancel:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker {
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }

- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController: (ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person {
    ABMultiValueRef emailMultiValue = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonEmailProperty);
    NSArray *email = [(NSArray *)ABMultiValueCopyArrayOfAllValues(emailMultiValue) autorelease];
    CFRelease(emailMultiValue);
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];}
- (BOOL)peoplePickerNavigationController:(ABPeoplePickerNavigationController *)peoplePicker shouldContinueAfterSelectingPerson:(ABRecordRef)person property:(ABPropertyID)property identifier:(ABMultiValueIdentifier)identifier{
    return NO;
}
```